# Java instantiation exception class not found

Tags: java, instantiation

In my java project, I am getting this exception `Java.lang.InstantiationException`: Class `one.two.three.MyClass` not found.

However in my project the class is present under the source folder with the package name `zero.one.two.three.MyClass`

So as you can see in the above exception `zero` was missing. I can't edit the expected path because it's in a precompiled class file that I am using. So what I did was created a package `one.two.three` under `src` folder and place `MyClass` inside to have a class where it is expected.

But I am still getting the same error.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: please provide some sample code as well as the stacktrace of your exceptions

Comment: It would be better if you provide a snapshot of the project structure. That would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry it's a proprietary code piece and I am not allowed to share the code or snapshot.

Comment: I really don't understand your question, the answer seems to be as simple as change your code by refering the class by it's correct package. Please provide more information about your code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, inside your pre-compiled class, package has set to

`package one.two.three.MyClass`

So, you can try something like this:

- Use a [decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) and decompile your so called pre-compiled
  class.
- Create a new class accordingly to the package structure and paste
  that code inside that class.

Comment: Thanks for the help